# Go to last heading of style heading level 2

Tags: vba, ms-word

I’m drawing a blank.
I want to `GoTo` the last Heading with `Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(“Heading 2”)`

I will then execute a find and replace all with `.Wrap = wdFindStop`.

I have the code for the second but. Just drawing a blank on the first part.

I haven’t tried it yet. I’m drawing a blank.

Comment: Unclear what the question is.

Comment: In the Word Find/Replace dialog box <<More options>>there is a drop down menu labelled search.  One of the options is Up.  What do you think that does?

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=7
```

Worked for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is really very simple. Word's built-in Find function can be set to search either forwards, or backwards. Searching backwards the last occurrence of Heading 2 will be the first.

```
Sub FindLastHeading2()
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2)
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = False
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = True
        End With
        If .Find.Execute Then
            'do what you need to do with the found range
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```